# How to mock a method call with an integer argument greater then X

Tags: mocking, mockito

How can I mock a method call with Mockito with an integer argument value greater then X?

I would like to write something like this:

```java
doReturn("FooBar").when(persons).getPersons(Mockito.gt(10));
```

Comment: This should now work, gt is a matcher

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mockito uses the matchers of Hamcrest. All of Mockitos argument matchers use these matchers to match the provided argument in a handy and type-safe way.

Mockito provides also the method `argThat(Matcher)` to use any matcher implementation of Hamcrest or custom `Matcher` implementation. There are also specialised versions as `intThat(Matcher)` for all primitved types.

So, knowing that, I rewrote the mocking of the method call:

```java
doReturn("FooBar")
   .when(persons)
   .getPersons(Mockito.intThat(Matchers.greaterThan(10));
```

Comment: +1 for finding a pre-existing matcher that does the job.

Answer (score 7):

**Mockito 2**

Hamcrest is no longer a dependency to Mockito matchers.

However, I found `MockitoHamcrest` which seems to provide interoperability with Hamcrest matchers. Applied to the example in question, it would look like this:

```
doReturn("FooBar").when(persons)
        .getPersons(MockitoHamcrest.intThat(Matchers.greaterThan(10)));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use AdditionalMatchers.gt:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;
import static org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.gt;
...
@Mock
private WalletService walletService;
...
@Before...
when(walletService.withdraw(eq(777), gt(1000), 
eq("USD"))).thenReturn(INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS);
...
@Test...
```

Comment: It's worth saying, this also works with Scala + Mockito. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Write a Hamcrest `Matcher<Integer>` by extending [ArgumentMatcher](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) (named IntGreaterThan, for example), and then use

```
doReturn("FooBar").when(persons).getPersons(intThat(MyMatchers.isGreatherThan(10)));
```

where `MyMatchers.isGreaterThan(10)` creates a new instance of your IntGreatherThan matcher.

If you static import `MyMatchers.isGreaterThan`, it becomes

```
doReturn("FooBar").when(persons).getPersons(intThat(isGreatherThan(10)));
```

Comment: +1.  But couldn't you use the existing Hamcrest greaterThan matcher instead of writing your own?

Comment: If such a matcher exists, then sure you can use it.

Comment: Yes, there is such a matcher. I just figured out the same as you.